# ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_14: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

Tags: python, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am building a cnn_rnn network for image classification. I am getting an error while running the following python code in my jupyter notebook.

```
     # model
     model1 = Sequential()
     # first convolutional layer
     model1.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),activation='relu',input_shape(160, 120, 3)))
     # second convolutional layer
     model1.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
     #Adding a pooling Layer
     model1.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3)))
     #Adding dropouts
     model1.add(Dropout(0.25))
     # flatten and put a fully connected layer
     model1.add(Flatten())
     model1.add(Dense(32, activation='relu')) # fully connected

     #Adding RNN N/W
     model1.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True))
     model1.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(5, activation='softmax')))
```

I also tried adding input_shape=(160, 120, 3) as a parameter to the LSTM function but to no avail. Please Help!

P.S: I also tried using GRU instead of LSTM but got the same error.

Update: Please note the model.summary() results
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuqOp.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your error is due to your use of Flatten and Dense BEFORE the LSTM layer.

LSTM layers require the input to be in the shape of (Batchsize x Length x Feature depth0) (or some variant), whereas your flatten changes the Conv2D output from (B x H x W x F) to (B x W  * F * H)  if that makes sense. If you want to use this architecture, I'd recommend using a Reshape layer to flatten the dimension you want, and using a Conv1D of kernel size 1 (same as a fully-connected layer) before the LSTM layer.

Or, if you want to use this exact code, add this before your LSTM layer and it should work:

> model1.add(Reshape(target_shape=(1,54*40,32))

It's 54 and 40 due a pool_size of (3,3).

Comment: Thanks a lot.However,could you elaborate on the calculation which gives 54*40?

Comment: The above statement throws an error: "ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged"

Comment: Ok, I must have gotten the shape incorrect. Can you tell me the size of the output of your dense operator please?

Comment: Please check the updated qustion. I have added a picture of the model.summary() results.

Comment: I'm confused... What do you want your LSTM layer to iterate over?